# Difference between a Raider and a Raider Scum?

Tags: fallout-4

I've came across many Raider groups and some groups have Raider and some have Raider Scums.

So what is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Raider Scum are higher level than the normal raiders in an area, so have more HP and better equipment. [See this page for more information, as well as the other types of raider.](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Raider_(Fallout_4))

All leveled enemies have different variations, for example Deathclaws and Savage Deathclaws.